# GitHub How to supplant known-defective Master with an authoritative Branch

Tags: git, github

I'm doing a single-programmer project, but using two alternate development rigs.  At one point, Master was contaminated with a fatal bug that cannot be debugged.  To rescue the 15,000 line project, I Branched off of a known good commit to the Master (a rollback branch).  I've been committing to this Branch for several months (unable to figure out yet how to cleanly supplant the defective Master).

I need to supplant the Master with the Branch.  There are unknown bugs in Master, likely in ASCII datafiles, and it would be foolish to risk reinfecting this project during the Merge.  Git does NOT do well with conflict resolution in datafiles.

In Eclipse, I entered a tentative Merge from the Master to bring together the Branch, and am looking at a "Conflicts master" (root of the current Eclipse project)  It won't allow me to commit anything because of these datafile conflicts.

Eclipse Git won't let me simply start over again on the Merge with these datafiles deleted from the Master (which I did directly thru the GitHub website).

Is there a way from the GitHub website to supplant the Master with the Branch, and then just go forward?

Answer (score 0):

To [start over again on the merge you have to do a hard reset](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Aborting_Merge) first.

To replace a branch you have to do push with the *force* option (since the history of the overwritten branch will be lost). Probably you can also use the web interface, but this requires a number of steps (most of them on the `.../branches` page):

1. Set another branch than `master` as default (this is only necessary if you want to have `master` instead of `main`)
2. Delete the `master` branch
3. [Create a new `master` (or `main`) branch](https://github.blog/2013-01-09-create-and-delete-branches/) based on the branch you want to use instead
4. Set the new branch as default
5. You might delete the branch that was used as the base for the new branch

Answer (score 0):

Since it was only 2 ASCII spreadsheet files that were posing conflicts in the merge (and holding up its completion), I attached the Team / Ignore attribute to these 2 files and their parent folder (which also carried a red "conflict" marker).  This allowed the 15,000 lines of source code to be merged into Master.

I may keep the "ignore" attribute "on" for these datafiles.  As stated in the OP, line-by-line version control is ill suited to tracking changes in these spreadsheet files.
It might be simpler to post these files at the time of major releases (which would entail taking "off" the ignore during those commits).